# Inner Product Uniqueness

Tags: vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

So an inner product satisfies these properties:

- $ \bf x \cdot \bf y = \bf y \cdot \bf x $
- $ \bf x \cdot (\bf y + \bf z) = \bf x \cdot \bf y + \bf x \cdot \bf z $
- $ \alpha ( \bf x \cdot \bf y) = (\alpha \bf x) \cdot \bf y  $
- $ \bf x \cdot \bf x \ge 0\quad \text {and} \quad x\cdot x = 0\iff x = 0$

Now for $R^n$, the inner product is just the dot product. But **is the dot product the only map** that satisfies these conditions, or can there be others as well? I'm not interested in trivial extensions to the dot product like $\bf x \cdot \bf y = (\sum_i x_i y_i)/k $ where k is just some constant, because this isn't really different.

Is there some totally different function, such that:

$$
f(\bf x, \bf y) = k
$$

Where x and y are vectors and k is a constant, that satisfies all of those properties? Or are those four conditions enough to force us to adopt this form in $R^n$?

Comment: In your definition, you says that $x\cdot x>0$ if and only if $x=0$ but it's a mistake. Should be $x\cdot x=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: It's not really clear what you consider "trivial extensions" or "really different"; it would make the question easier to address if you made this more precise. Given any symmetric real matrix $A$ with positive eigenvalues, ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y} := {\bf y}^{\top} A {\bf x}$ is an inner product on $\Bbb R^n$, and this accounts for all such inner products. On the other hand, for any inner product $\cdot$ on $\Bbb R^n$, there is a basis ${\bf e}_i$ such that ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y} = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i y_i$, where $x_i, y_i$ are the coefficients of ${\bf x}, {\bf y}$ w.r.t. this basis.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, You're right, is that fixed?

Comment: I'll clarify @Travis, sorry about that, Basically, any version of the dot product with a constant in front is trivial. I'm looking for examples like the one José Provided.

Comment: Nope. Check the answer of @José Carlos Santos.

Comment: Imposing any new basis on $\Bbb R^n$, keeping the old scalar product with respect to the actual vectors, and see how it behaves with respect to the new coordinates will give you a "new" inner product. For instance, your $\bf x \cdot \bf y = (\sum_i x_i y_i)/k$ is made in this way by shortening all basis vectors by a factor of $\sqrt k$, but there are other things you can do (scale the basis vectors differently, and skewing, for instance).

Comment: @CarlosJiménez, sorry yep, thats right! My mistake again :)

Comment: @Arthur, Could you recommend a reference for this? I'd like to look into it if possible :)

Comment: I don't think that this has a reference as such. It's basically the same as Travis' suggestion, only phrased differently. I think Josè's suggestion also falls under this, but I can't immediately tell which basis one would use to make it.

Comment: @user2662833 In that case taking any $A$ in the construction I mentioned---other than a multiple of the identity matrix, which will give the constant multiples of the standard dot product that you want to avoid---will give such an example. In particular, the matrix $A = \pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}$ yields Jose's example.

Comment: Also, after actually setting up the equations on papaer and solving them, it seems that the basis $(\sqrt2, 0), (-1/\sqrt2, \sqrt{3/2})$ will give José's example through my approach. Alternatively, if one likes symmetry, one can use $\frac12(1 + \sqrt3, 1-\sqrt3), \frac12(1-\sqrt3, 1+\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last item should be

- $\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{x}\geqslant 0$ and $\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{x}=0\iff\mathbf{x}=0$.

Yes, there are other inner products. For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can define$$(x_1,x_2).(y_1,y_2)=2x_1y_1-x_1y_2-x_2y_1+2x_2y_2.$$

Comment: Awesome awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, I reasoned this sort of thing should be possible, but couldn't figure one out. Would it be possible to share how you arrived at this?

Comment: I think $x_1 y_1 $ is right upon calculation, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Arthur I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @user2662833 In order to construct examples such as this one, I use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): I take a symmetric real matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ such that, for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $\det\bigl((a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant k}\bigr)>0$ and then I define$$\langle v,w\rangle=v.A.w^T.$$

Comment: Thank you :) I hadn't heard of this before!